# Viewing the content of a Spark Dataframe Column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I'm using Spark 1.3.1.

I am trying to view the values of a Spark dataframe column in Python.  With a Spark dataframe, I can do `df.collect()` to view the contents of the dataframe, but there is no such method for a Spark dataframe column as best as I can see.

For example, the dataframe `df` contains a column named `'zip_code'`.  So I can do `df['zip_code']` and it turns a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.Column` type, but I can't find a way to view the values in `df['zip_code']`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can access underlying `RDD` and map over it

```
df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.zip_code).collect()
```

You can also use `select` if you don't mind results wrapped using `Row` objects:

```
df.select('zip_code').collect()
```

Finally, if you simply want to inspect content then `show` method should be enough:

```
df.select('zip_code').show()
```

Comment: The **question** in question here isn't, _"How do I view the contents of a **Dataframe**, but only one column of it?"_, but rather _"Given an object of type **Column**, and no objects of type **Dataframe**, how do I view the contents of that **Column**?_

Comment: @JordanPilat You don't. `Column` is not bounded to any execution plan. It is nothing more than a symbol.

Comment: Good answer!  To clarify, `Column` does not contain any data in and of itself, and only represents a series of _0 or more_ transformations of _1 or more_ specific `DataFrame` columns.  Thus, it makes no sense to refer to it outside of the context of the `DataFrame` from which it was spawned.  Right?

Comment: @JordanPilat It can constructed from an expression but at the end of the day it has no meaning alone. Consider this: `$"foo"`. It creates an object of class  `ColumnName` which is a subclass of the `Column`. Alone it has no meaning. I can evaluate it using different DF's and get different results (or exceptions). If you ever used R think about the `formulas`.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply write:

```
df.select('your column's name').show()
```

In your case here, it will be:

```
df.select('zip_code').show()
```

Answer (score 5):

To view the complete content:

```
df.select("raw").take(1).foreach(println)
```

(`show` will show you an overview).