# Ambiguity in definition of Spark "Column": What does it contain and how/when is the data used?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm working through [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-withcolumn)
on manipulating data frame `Column` objects.  The doc string for the
[Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.html#pyspark.sql.Column)
class shows a `Column`s columnar data and heading (Annex A below).  In
contrast, the doc string for the
[col](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.col.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col)
method shows that a `Column` can specify *just* a heading, without
containing any data (Annex B below).

While a `Column` can result from *extracting* columnar data from a
DataFrame, and possibly performing operations on that, in neither of
the above two manifestations does a `Column` maintain a pointer to a
source table for either the heading or data.  The doc string for
`DataFrame`'s
[withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn)
method muddies that up for me.  Its prototype says to not refer to
external data frames:

```
def withColumn(self, colName: str, col: Column) -> "DataFrame":
        <...snip...>
    The column expression must be an expression over this
    :class:`DataFrame`; attempting to add a column from some other
    :class:`DataFrame` will raise an error.
        <...snip...>
```

As mentioned in my 2nd paragraph above, however, `Column`s don't
*seem* to refer back to any data frames for either name information or
columnar data.  All the information seems to be self-contained within
the `Column` object itself.

***How can I understand/resolve this apparent contradiction in what a
`Column` is, and how should I understand `withColumn`'s stipulation
against referring to external data frames?***

Further examples of the disparity can be found from other tutorials.
The `DataFrame` `df` from [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-rename-dataframe-column).
can be used to show that a `Column` object resulting from evaluating
an expression contains the columnar data, e.g., `df.salary+1`:

```
df.show(2)
+-----------------+----------+------+------+
|             name|       dob|gender|salary|
+-----------------+----------+------+------+
| {James, , Smith}|1991-04-01|     M|  3000|
|{Michael, Rose, }|2000-05-19|     M|  4000|
+-----------------+----------+------+------+

df.withColumn("salary",df.salary+1).show(2)
+-----------------+----------+------+------+
|             name|       dob|gender|salary|
+-----------------+----------+------+------+
| {James, , Smith}|1991-04-01|     M|  3001|
|{Michael, Rose, }|2000-05-19|     M|  4001|
+-----------------+----------+------+------+
```

In contrast, the identical `DataFrame` from [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-withcolumn) can
be used to show a "salary" column with no data.  The tutorial uses
this code:

```
df.withColumn("salary",col("salary").cast("Integer")).show()
```

The key difference here is that `col("salary")` makes *no* reference
to `DataFrame` `df`.  In contrast to `df.salary+1`, therefore, the
`Column` object that results from evaluating `col("salary")` cannot
possibly contain any columnar data.  The only possibility is that
`col("salary").cast("Integer")` contains only the column name and
(Spark) data type.  This means that `withColumn` takes those limited
details from the Column object, looks up that column in it's own
DataFrame (the object through which `withColumn` is invoked, `df`),
and obtains the data in that way.

Since a `Column` object has (at least) these two manifestations, I
can picture various ways in which it might behave:

- The `Column` object result from expression evaluation *sometimes*
  contains the column data
- *Sometimes*, a `Column` object contains only the name of a column
  and possibly the data type.  If `withColumn` gets such a 2nd
  argument (in the above context, *not* in its signature), perhaps it
  looks up the named column in in the `DataFrame` through which it is
  invoked
- If a `Column` object is the result of an *expression* with
  *operations*, but it refers to no concrete columnar data, it is
  conceivable that the operations are stored in the column object
  *symbolically* so that `withColumn` knows what to do when it
  retrieves the data from the `DataFrame` object through which it was
  invoked
- If the expression that yields a `Column` object refers to a column
  in a source `DataFrame`, such as in `df.salary+1` above, perhaps
  the `Column` object internally maintains a reference to the source
  column and stores the operations in the expression symbolically.
  When the resulting columnar data is needed, the data is retrieved
  from the source column and the operations performed.  This
  speculated behaviour allows `Column` objects to refer to external
  `DataFrame`s; the warnings *against* such external references then
  make sense.

With the limited doc string information, there are many possibilities
in what to expect of `Column`'s implementation and behaviour.
It's hard to get an understanding of the intended operation and behaviour.  Hopefully, someone can shed some light and drastically reduce the
possibilities.  ***If there is more detailed documentation for Spark modules, classes, and methods, I would appreciate a pointer to it.***

Thanks.

## Annex A: `Column` class doc string excerpt

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...      [(2, "Alice"), (5, "Bob")], ["age", "name"])

Select a column out of a DataFrame
>>> df.name
Column<'name'>
>>> df["name"]
Column<'name'>

Create from an expression

>>> df.age + 1
Column<...>
>>> 1 / df.age
Column<...>
```

## Annex B: `col` function doc string excerpt

```
>>> col('x')
Column<'x'>
>>> column('x')
Column<'x'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is not a complete answer, but it is the best answer that
I could find over weeks.

According to the ***comments*** of [this
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31124244/2153235), a `Column`
object does *not* store data.  It stores the *column name*.  From the
`Column.cast()` example in the question posted above, it may also store a
*data type.*

It is very possible that it can store a *reference to a source
`DataFrame`.*  We see evidence of this in the examples of the posted
question, where `df.` prefixes the column name.  If references to a
source table *cannot* be stored with a `Column` object, then there is
little need to prefix column names with `DataFrame` names.  If a
`Column`
object can in fact store a reference to source `DataFrame`, then it is
conceivable and plausible that specifying a source `DataFrame` name as a
prefix allows the resulting `Column` object to inherit the data type
from the named column in the source `DataFrame`.  As described in the
question, `withColumn`'s warning against referencing external
`DataFrame`'s only makes sense if a `Column` object can contain
a reference to a source `DataFrame`.

Finally, as suggested in the posted question, it seems that an
expression that involves column operations and yields a `Column`
object *also* stores the operations symbolically.  For example,
`df.salary+1` might store the column name `salary`, the source
`DataFrame` `df`, and the operation `+1`.  We know that `df.salary` is a
`Column` object that stores no data, so there seems to be little
logical alternative the the supposition that the column meta-data
(name and possibly type) are be stored along with the source
`DataFrame`
`df` and the `+1` operation.

In terms of when the data is fetched and when the operations are
performed, it could be that `withColumn` evaluates the column expression, fetches
the data, and performs the operation.  If there is no `DataFrame`
referenced, then perhaps `withColumn` looks for an identically named
column in the `DataFrame` object through which it was called.

It is also possible that the fetching of data and performance of
column operations is not strictly the responsibility of the
`withColumn` method.  It could be that the operator methods of
`Column`
objects (e.g., `+`, `-`, etc.) are defined such that they look up the
source data, fetch it, and perform the operation corresponding to the
operator.

I see the latter as less likely because some `Column` objects lack a
reference to a source `DataFrame`, so it would not be possible to "look
them up".  If this is a valid point, then it is more likely that data
fetching and performance of operations is done by `withColumn`, since
it has a host `DataFrame` through which `withColumn` is invoked.  Hence,
`Column` objects that lack a reference to a `DataFrame`, can be looked up
through the host `DataFrame`.

As should be clear, the answer is somewhat speculative, though
carefully reasoned.  It would be nice to have more transparency into
what a `Column` object is and how it is meant to work.  Short of reverse
engineering the source code, if there is a better reference that
describes the `Column` class, it could enhance this answer or provide a
better alternative.