# How is Spark's "exploding" of array/map fields a SELECT operation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, explode

I am new to Python a Spark, currently working through [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows)
on Spark's `explode` operation for array/map fields of a DataFrame.

Based on the very first section 1 (*PySpark explode array or map
column to rows*), it's very intuitive.  The minimum working example
DataFrame is created the Annex below.  The schema and DataFrame
table are:

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- knownLanguages: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- properties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|name      |knownLanguages     |properties                   |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
|James     |[Java, Scala]      |{eye -> brown, hair -> black}|
|Michael   |[Spark, Java, null]|{eye -> null, hair -> brown} |
|Robert    |[CSharp, ]         |{eye -> , hair -> red}       |
|Washington|null               |null                         |
|Jefferson |[1, 2]             |{}                           |
+----------+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

The `explode` function is illustrated as follows:

```
>>> df \
... .select(df.name,explode(df.knownLanguages)) \
... .show()
+---------+------+
|name     |col   |
+---------+------+
|James    |Java  |
|James    |Scala |
|Michael  |Spark |
|Michael  |Java  |
|Michael  |null  |
|Robert   |CSharp|
|Robert   |      |
|Jefferson|1     |
|Jefferson|2     |
+---------+------+
```

The `explode` function is shown in the context of a SELECT query,
however, which I find to be very unintuitive.  SELECT prunes away rows
and never increases the height of a data frame.  Only joins
potentially increase height, but even there, the filtering of rows is
applied to a Cartesian join [1], so is still a potential reduction in
height rather than an increase.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but the
above SELECT is not being applied to a join, since it is invoked as a
method of `DataFrame` `df`.

I tried to better see how `explode` fits SELECT through the latter's
doc string: "Projects a set of expressions and returns a new
:class:`DataFrame`".  *Projection* refers to [choosing column
expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031101).  I unsuccessfully
tried to get insight into how the above `explode` code fits SELECTion
by examining its content:

```
explode(df.knownLanguages) # Shows no columnar data
Out[114]: Column<'explode(knownLanguages)'>
```

Later, I found that it is not possible to examine the columnar data
content of `Column` object, as described
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218681).

The prototype for `explode` returns a `Column` object while the doc
string says that it "Returns a new row for each element in the given
array or map".  It's difficult to picture such column, as there is no
"given array or map" -- there are as many heterogenous arrays/maps as
there are records in `DataFrame` `df`.

Even if we accept that the `Column` object [doesn't *contain* such
columnar data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218681), it's
necessary to picture how such a column would be conceptually
constructed in order to see how the SELECT makes sense.
I can't come up with such a column of data that would make sense in
the SELECT query because no matter how the `explode` column is constructed, it will be
of a different height than `DataFrame` `df`.

***Would it be correct to conclude that `explode()` can yield no column
expression that would fit SELECT's
[projection/selection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1031101) operation
as applied `DataFrame` `df`, and that it is simply a signal to the
`select()` method to create a new `DataFrame` by replicating each
record $i$ by $n_i$ times, where $n_i$ is the number of items in the
record's array/map?***

I'm just starting to find may way around Spark.  I anticipate, however, that if `explode()` breaks the projection/selection model of SELECT, it may be difficult to craft more complex queries than in the tutorial based on knowledge of designed-for behaviour.

### Notes

**[1]** SELECT filters a Cartesian join in concept, though of course,
not in execution.  This is reflected by the fact that early SQL used
WHERE in place of ON.  All the WHERE clauses are (conceptually)
applied to a Cartesian join.

## Annex: Create minimum working example DataFrame table

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pyspark-by-examples').getOrCreate()

arrayData = [
        ('James',['Java','Scala'],{'hair':'black','eye':'brown'}),
        ('Michael',['Spark','Java',None],{'hair':'brown','eye':None}),
        ('Robert',['CSharp',''],{'hair':'red','eye':''}),
        ('Washington',None,None),
        ('Jefferson',['1','2'],{})
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=arrayData, schema = ['name','knownLanguages','properties'])
```

Comment: `explode` is not a select operation, but a column operation that returns a new column. as in doc - `pyspark.sql.functions.explode(col: ColumnOrName) → pyspark.sql.column.Column`. you can use it in `withColumn`. all of this is a projection because a new column is generated.

Comment: @samkart: I thought that projection is taking a set of points in $n$-dimensional space and smooshing them into a subspace represented by some of the $n$ dimensions, but not all of them. For example, taking a set of points in a 3D space with axes $x, y,$ and $z$ and flatteng them onto the $xy$ plane by dropping the $z$ coordinates. That's what happens when you SELECT some columns from a relational data table (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra))). When you say "all of this is a projection", what is the relational data table to which it is being applied?

Comment: It *seems* like the SELECT projection is applied to DataFrame `df` because it is being invoked as its method, but that can't be right because the `explode()` column doesn't even match the height of `df`.  A SELECT operation in relational algebra specifies columns from a single relational data table, and it only makes sense if the columns are the same height. Even when selecting from a JOIN, the SELECTion is being done from the single table that results from the JOIN. The DataFrame.select() method is described as a projection, so this concept of projection should still apply.

Comment: the `explain()` method of dataframe can help you somewhat. try it

Comment: I believe you're overthinking here. "projection", here, means selecting columns (or projecting the dataframe with few or more columns). i don't believe it has anything to do with algebra.

Comment: I tried `df.explain()` using its various options. I had to correct a typo in the Annex to the question before I could generate `DataFrame` `df`. Honestly, I'm not sure what to make of the technical details in terms of the question. As for pojection, it's not overthinking at all. This is what SELECTion is. If it's not as described, then it isn't SELECTion or projection in relational algebra, which underpins all of relational databases. It might be something else, something very useful, but that's what I'm trying to get a bead on.

Comment: Just to clarify the reason for this question, I'll elaborate on the closing paragraph of the question. Sometimes, a lot of careful planning goes into crafting complex queries based on the relational algebra model. The incorporation of SQL functionality into 4th generation languages (Matlab, Python, R, arguably Java with lots of library support) makes it necessary to be sure of what functionality follows the relational algebra model and which do not.